# Bootstrap modal footer positioning when using a percent height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal which is horizontally and vertically centered and has a percent height (90% of the window height). When the modal content vertically overflows, the footer is in the correct place. When there is less content than the height of the modal, the footer is too high. See image.

[image]

My fix for this was to do:

```
.modal-footer {
   position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It appeared perfect at first, but then I noticed that when resizing the height of the page to be smaller, the border of the footer is not at the top of the footer. I coloured it red so you can easily see:

[image]

So what is the best way to keep the footer at the bottom of the modal? position absolute like I did? If this is the case then how do I fix the footer going higher than the border? Or is there a better way than position:absolute?

[Please use this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/927/) as it is a replica of mine.

Here is all my code:

css

```
.vertical-alignment-helper {
    display:table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 95%;
        margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.vertical-align-center {
    /* To center vertically */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.modal-content {
    /* Bootstrap sets the size of the modal in the modal-dialog class, we need to inherit it */
    width:inherit;
    height: 90%;
    /* To center horizontally */
    margin: auto;
box-shadow:  0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.76);
}

.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-footer {
   position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

html

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" id="result-details-modal">
            <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
    <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel vehicula erat. Phasellus vestibulum leo eu mi tempor blandit. Suspendisse eget iaculis lectus. Donec vitae tempus enim, quis tristique magna. Donec lobortis, sem ac pretium viverra, leo nisl consequat arcu, sit amet ullamcorper nunc turpis ac erat. In rutrum auctor ligula, quis mattis enim lacinia eu. Aliquam at magna a erat laoreet iaculis quis a justo. Donec porttitor vulputate massa, nec suscipit nisi mollis sed.</p>
                <p>Praesent sit amet porttitor magna, auctor feugiat tellus. Sed venenatis tortor turpis, vel vestibulum eros pulvinar et. Pellentesque hendrerit diam quis dui euismod tincidunt. Sed sit amet mauris ipsum. Integer in magna tellus. In tincidunt mi quis nunc gravida sollicitudin. Aliquam ac dui eget erat consequat volutpat in eu magna.</p>
                <p>Sed feugiat bibendum leo consequat convallis. Donec facilisis, turpis a scelerisque venenatis, felis diam dictum tortor, vitae imperdiet tortor ligula eu lectus. Donec iaculis semper elementum. Nullam dapibus porttitor magna quis convallis. Morbi porttitor quam non magna ullamcorper rhoncus. Phasellus sit amet nunc at turpis pharetra luctus a a massa. Praesent luctus massa in odio faucibus eleifend.</p>
                <p>In eget lobortis leo, ut luctus odio. Mauris pharetra erat ac tellus hendrerit semper. Cras faucibus ipsum id ante hendrerit rutrum. Donec vitae ullamcorper arcu. Aliquam pellentesque faucibus placerat. Aliquam erat volutpat. In tincidunt metus sit amet ligula sagittis vehicula. Pellentesque velit quam, hendrerit a erat ac, fermentum tincidunt enim. Cras suscipit justo nec consectetur lacinia.</p>
                <p>Cras pellentesque urna a leo egestas, at ullamcorper augue suscipit. Nulla id lacinia magna, non iaculis est. Praesent a placerat augue, eget eleifend purus. Aenean dignissim, orci et rutrum facilisis, tellus massa porta nulla, quis hendrerit dui ipsum vitae urna. In mattis lectus dolor, id venenatis lectus pellentesque at. Suspendisse posuere metus vel bibendum dignissim. Fusce interdum magna id libero scelerisque suscipit. Duis orci augue, rhoncus eget pharetra ac, viverra nec magna. In accumsan nulla ac suscipit pellentesque. Nulla iaculis luctus tellus, at ultricies urna hendrerit a. Aenean vehicula sodales varius. Duis sodales hendrerit odio non sagittis.</p>
                                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vel vehicula erat. Phasellus vestibulum leo eu mi tempor blandit. Suspendisse eget iaculis lectus. Donec vitae tempus enim, quis tristique magna. Donec lobortis, sem ac pretium viverra, leo nisl consequat arcu, sit amet ullamcorper nunc turpis ac erat. In rutrum auctor ligula, quis mattis enim lacinia eu. Aliquam at magna a erat laoreet iaculis quis a justo. Donec porttitor vulputate massa, nec suscipit nisi mollis sed.</p>
                <p>Praesent sit amet porttitor magna, auctor feugiat tellus. Sed venenatis tortor turpis, vel vestibulum eros pulvinar et. Pellentesque hendrerit diam quis dui euismod tincidunt. Sed sit amet mauris ipsum. Integer in magna tellus. In tincidunt mi quis nunc gravida sollicitudin. Aliquam ac dui eget erat consequat volutpat in eu magna.</p>
                <p>Sed feugiat bibendum leo consequat convallis. Donec facilisis, turpis a scelerisque venenatis, felis diam dictum tortor, vitae imperdiet tortor ligula eu lectus. Donec iaculis semper elementum. Nullam dapibus porttitor magna quis convallis. Morbi porttitor quam non magna ullamcorper rhoncus. Phasellus sit amet nunc at turpis pharetra luctus a a massa. Praesent luctus massa in odio faucibus eleifend.</p>
                <p>In eget lobortis leo, ut luctus odio. Mauris pharetra erat ac tellus hendrerit semper. Cras faucibus ipsum id ante hendrerit rutrum. Donec vitae ullamcorper arcu. Aliquam pellentesque faucibus placerat. Aliquam erat volutpat. In tincidunt metus sit amet ligula sagittis vehicula. Pellentesque velit quam, hendrerit a erat ac, fermentum tincidunt enim. Cras suscipit justo nec consectetur lacinia.</p>
                <p>Cras pellentesque urna a leo egestas, at ullamcorper augue suscipit. Nulla id lacinia magna, non iaculis est. Praesent a placerat augue, eget eleifend purus. Aenean dignissim, orci et rutrum facilisis, tellus massa porta nulla, quis hendrerit dui ipsum vitae urna. In mattis lectus dolor, id venenatis lectus pellentesque at. Suspendisse posuere metus vel bibendum dignissim. Fusce interdum magna id libero scelerisque suscipit. Duis orci augue, rhoncus eget pharetra ac, viverra nec magna. In accumsan nulla ac suscipit pellentesque. Nulla iaculis luctus tellus, at ultricies urna hendrerit a. Aenean vehicula sodales varius. Duis sodales hendrerit odio non sagittis.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this.

First, you can use a fixed height on `.modal-body`. The downside is that this is an easy way to break your page, or at least make it less maintainable, and you will likely need to use a carefully defined `calc()` in your CSS, which is better if you can avoid it.

Second, use flexbox to do the magic for you. The downside is that you will have issues with older versions of android, and IE, though virtually all modern browsers support it. Here is an example I whipped up: http://codepen.io/AsLittleDesign/pen/WGwzxk

There are better methods for creating modal dialogues IMO, since in this method you are defining a fixed height, when you should consider creating a modal that doesn't take up more space than it needs. Flexbox, or a table layout is a good way to go about doing this (more the former than latter).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding height:100% to the modal body and remove the absolute positioning declaration:

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzoaaxfr/1/